# disable GROUP BY column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I apologize if this is a duplicate (it may well be). I have spent quite a while searching and can't find a precise answer to my question.

I have built a SQL function (in MSSQL) that returns rows grouped either by year,month or just by year, depending on the argument:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_report (@grouping VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT
    YEAR(t.my_date) as my_year,
    CASE when @grouping = 'monthly' THEN MONTH(t.my_date) ELSE null END as my_month,
    count(t.row_id) as num_rows,
    round(avg(my_val),4) as avg_my_val
FROM
    my_schema.my_info t
GROUP BY 
    year(t.my_date),
    CASE when @grouping = 'monthly' THEN month(t.my_date) ELSE null END
)
```

This succeeds in giving me a grouping by month or by year, depending on how I want the report to go.

But ideally I want the option of having `@grouping = 'none'` to eliminate the grouping entirely and just display a list of items. It's possible that I'm trying to force this query to do too much, but maybe not. I've tried something like `GROUP BY 0` but that doesn't do what I want, and `GROUP BY rand()` seems too messy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: MSSQL, sorry I'll add this to the question

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
use tsql2012

create table dbo.test18
(
    year int not null,
    month int not null,
    value int
);

insert into dbo.test18
values (2017, 4, 250), (2017, 4, 150), (2017, 4, 660), (2017, 4, 1110), (2017, 3, 1250), (2017, 2, 2540), (2017, 3, 2500)

declare @a varchar(30) = 'none'

select * from (
    select grouping_id(year, month, value) as gr_id, year, month, sum(value) as sm
    from dbo.test18
    group by grouping sets((year), (month), (year, month), (year, month, value))
) t
where 
    gr_id < case when @a = 'none' then 1 else 999 end
    and gr_id > case when @a = 'none' then -1 else 0 end
```

Comment: This answer looks to give me what I want so I accepted it. My project plans have changed, but if I use this in the future it looks like I would just need to add a where condition to look for the correct grouping_id.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parameterize grouping - similarly you cannot parameterize query structure (because it will result in a different execution plan which cannot be cached).

There are three solutions:

1. Use Dynamic-SQL (i.e. build a SQL string within T-SQL, this would have to be in a sproc, not a UDF).
2. Use an ORM which dynamically generates SQL anyway (e.g. Linq-to-Entities or NHibernate, etc)
3. Create a second UDF for the non-grouped version.